# О "сворачивании"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильнее: "сворачивается" или "свертывается"? Или "свертывается" - это о крови?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Словаре русского языка под ред. А.П. Евгеньевой (МАС) есть толкование глагола СВЕРНУТЬСЯ (глагол совершенного вида). Видовую пару с ним образует глагол СВЕРТЫВАТЬСЯ (глагол несовершенного вида). И почти в каждом из значений (глагол СВЕРНУТЬСЯ многозначный) есть пометка: "(несов. также СВОРАЧИВАТЬСЯ)". Т.е. и кровь, и молоко могут и *сворачиваться*, и *свертываться*.